# Scrapy Open SSl Error

Tags: python, ssl, openssl, scrapy

I am new to scrapy and am trying to scrape the title for the following website
https://www.mdcalc.com/heart-score-major-cardiac-events

I reviewed all the previous posts on this subject but am still getting then open ssl error

Here is my code:
settings.py

```
DOWNLOADER_CLIENTCONTEXTFACTORY ='scrapy.core.downloader.contextfactory.ScrapyClientContextFactory'
```

Here is the code for my spider

```
import scrapy
from skitter.items import SkitterItem

class mdcalc(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "mdcalc"
    allowed_domains = "mdcalc.com"
    start_urls = ['https://www.mdcalc.com/heart-score-major-cardiac-events']

def parse(self, response) :
    item = SkitterItem()
    item['title'] = response.xpath('//h1//text()').extract()[0]
    yield item
```

When I run

```
curl localhost:6800/schedule.json -d project=skitter -d spider=mdcalc
```

Here is the error I get

```
2017-09-27 02:02:23+0000 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.24.6 started (bot: skitter)
2017-09-27 02:02:23+0000 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, 
http11
2017-09-27 02:02:23+0000 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: 
{'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'skitter.spiders', 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 
'SPIDER_MODULES': 
2017-09-27 02:02:23+0000 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: FeedExporter, 
LogStats, TelnetConsole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, SpiderState
2017-09-27 02:02:23+0000 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: 
RobotsTxtMiddleware, HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, 
UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, 
MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, 
CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2017-09-27 02:02:23+0000 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: 
HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, 
UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2017-09-27 02:02:23+0000 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: 
ElasticSearchPipeline
2017-09-27 02:02:23+0000 [mdcalc] INFO: Spider opened
2017-09-27 02:02:23+0000 [mdcalc] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), 
scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-09-27 02:02:23+0000 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 
127.0.0.1:6024
2017-09-27 02:02:23+0000 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 
127.0.0.1:6081
2017-09-27 02:02:23+0000 [mdcalc] DEBUG: Retrying <GET 
https://www.mdcalc.com/robots.txt> (failed 1 times): 
[<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'OpenSSL.SSL.Error'>>]
2017-09-27 02:02:27+0000 [mdcalc] DEBUG: Retrying <GET 
https://www.mdcalc.com/heart-score-major-cardiac-events> (failed 1 times): 
[<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'OpenSSL.SSL.Error'>>]
2017-09-27 02:02:32+0000 [mdcalc] DEBUG: Retrying <GET 
https://www.mdcalc.com/robots.txt> (failed 2 times): 
[<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'OpenSSL.SSL.Error'>>]
2017-09-27 02:02:38+0000 [mdcalc] DEBUG: Retrying <GET 
https://www.mdcalc.com/heart-score-major-cardiac-events> (failed 2 times): 
[<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'OpenSSL.SSL.Error'>>]
2017-09-27 02:02:45+0000 [mdcalc] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <GET 
https://www.mdcalc.com/robots.txt> (failed 3 times): 
[<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'OpenSSL.SSL.Error'>>]
2017-09-27 02:02:45+0000 [HTTP11ClientProtocol (TLSMemoryBIOProtocol),client] 
ERROR: Unhandled error in Deferred:
2017-09-27 02:02:45+0000 [HTTP11ClientProtocol (TLSMemoryBIOProtocol),client] 
Unhandled Error
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    Failure: twisted.web._newclient.ResponseNeverReceived: [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'OpenSSL.SSL.Error'>>]

2017-09-27 02:02:52+0000 [mdcalc] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <GET https://www.mdcalc.com/heart-score-major-cardiac-events> (failed 3 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'OpenSSL.SSL.Error'>>]
2017-09-27 02:02:52+0000 [mdcalc] ERROR: Error downloading <GET https://www.mdcalc.com/heart-score-major-cardiac-events>: [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'OpenSSL.SSL.Error'>>]
2017-09-27 02:02:52+0000 [mdcalc] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2017-09-27 02:02:52+0000 [mdcalc] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/exception_count': 6,
```

'downloader/exception_type_count/twisted.web._newclient.ResponseNeverReceived': 
    6,
        'downloader/request_bytes': 1614,
         'downloader/request_count': 6,
         'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 6,
         'finish_reason': 'finished',
         'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 27, 2, 2, 52, 62313),
         'log_count/DEBUG': 8,
         'log_count/ERROR': 3,
         'log_count/INFO': 7,
         'scheduler/dequeued': 3,
         'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 3,
         'scheduler/enqueued': 3,
         'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 3,
         'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 27, 2, 2, 23, 380740)}
    2017-09-27 02:02:52+0000 [mdcalc] INFO: Spider closed (finished)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Is there a way that I can run my curl command to avoid this error?

Comment: Could you post whole log/trace output, not just that snippet? I suspect there is some important information missing.

Comment: Works fine for me. So no issues with the site for sure. Try removing `DOWNLOADER_CLIENTCONTEXTFACTORY` from your settings and see if that helps. Also see if you have the latest scrapy version on the scrapyd server. use `pip install scrapy --force --upgrade` to get the latest one

Comment: @TomášLinhart just updated the post with the full output. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: @TarunLalwani Hi, I just deleted the DOWNLOADER_CLIENTCONTEXTFACTORY from my settings.py and updated my scrapy. Still getting the same error when I run my curl command

Comment: Try `curl https://www.mdcalc.com/heart-score-major-cardiac-events` on the scrapy server and see if it works. May be your server has been blocked?

Comment: @affemann2 Based on [this](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/1429) issues, I would try to play with `DOWNLOADER_CLIENT_TLS_METHOD` in your `settings.py`, e.g. try to set it to `SSLv3` and if it doesn't work, try `TLSv1.2` value.

Comment: @TomášLinhart. I just tried in my settings.py adding DOWNLOADER_CLIENT_TLS_METHOD = 'SSLv3' . Still got the same error. So tried it with 'TLSv1.2' Same error. Did I write the DOWNLOADER_CLIENT_TLS_METHOD correctly? Or do I need to add something else. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @TarunLalwani if I run curl https://www.mdcalc.com/heart-score-major-cardiac-events on my terminal it is able to connect with the site. It seems that it's only when I try to run my spider using curl localhost:6800/schedule.json -d project=skitter -d spider=mdcalc that it is not working. Do I need to add something to my settings.py to make the connection? Or is there a way to run the curl command so that it will work? Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: So are you saying that on same server the crawl runs without problem when run directly and doesn't when run through scrapyd?

Comment: @TarunLalwani. Yup. That's the problem.

Comment: Try to create a new virtual environment and then install scrapy and scrapyd in it and try again

Comment: @TarunLalwani No luck. Restarted my computer. Created a new virtual environment using docker. And still getting the same error

Comment: Open a issue with scrapy, not sure what is happening here

Comment: @TarunLalwani Will do. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

it's because of the version of python that scrapinghub cloud runs by default, which is 2.7, to fix that you have to specify which version of python your spider must use, python3, this link explain how to do it.
https://support.scrapinghub.com/support/solutions/articles/22000200387-deploying-python-3-spiders-to-scrapy-cloud